# R Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : polygon edge not found when plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I know there are other posts on this but I have tried all they suggested and nothing works, I used not to have this problem and now all of a sudden, while running code that I was running before, I started having this problem. I think it is related to a theme I am creating but I don't understand why this worked fine before and now it is giving me this problem. Also, sometimes the problem appears and sometimes it doesn't...again with the same code. Super weird!

```
theme_Publication <- function(base_size = 15, base_family = 'sans') {
  (theme_foundation(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family)
   + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2), face = 'bold', hjust = 0.5),
           text = element_text(),
           panel.background = element_rect(colour = NA),
           plot.background = element_rect(colour = NA),
           panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA),
           axis.title = element_text(face = 'bold', size = rel(1)),
           axis.title.y = element_text(angle=90,vjust =2),
           axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.2),
           axis.text = element_text(size = rel(0.8)),
           axis.line = element_line(colour='black', size = 1.2),
           axis.ticks = element_line(),
           panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
           panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
           legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA),
           legend.position = 'right',
           legend.key.size= unit(0.2, 'cm'),
           legend.margin = margin(t = 0, unit='cm'),
           legend.title = element_text(face='italic'),
           plot.margin=unit(c(2.5,5,2.5,5),'mm'),
           strip.background=element_rect(colour='#F0F0F0',fill='#F0F0F0'),
           strip.text = element_text(face='bold')
   )
  )
}

df <- data.frame(x = c(71.33,   74.98 ,  80 , 85.35  , 90.03),
                 y = c(119.17,  107.73 , 99.72 ,  75,  54.59))

(b = ggplot(df)+
    geom_col(aes(x, y), position = "dodge") +
    xlab('x') +
    ylab('y') +
    labs(title = 'Example') +
    theme_Publication())
```

when I run this code as it is sometimes R gives me this message:

```
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : polygon edge not found
```

I found a way around it:

```
(b = ggplot(df)+
geom_col(aes(x, y), position = "dodge") +
xlab('x') +
ylab('y') +
labs(title = 'Example') +
theme_Publication() + 
theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial")))
```

However if I do this then I cannot save this image as pdf which is a problem. I tried downloading the 'extrafont' package but when I look up the fonts of the package the list is empty. Please can someone help me? it's driving me insane.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

First of all install packages to get fonts like Arial:

```
library(ggthemes)
library(extrafont)
library(remotes)
remotes::install_version("Rttf2pt1", version = "1.3.8")
extrafont::font_import()
```

After that load the fonts:

```
# Load fonts
loadfonts(quiet = T)
fonts()
```

Small output because there are a lot of fonts:

```
fonts()
  [1] ".SF Compact Rounded"     ".Keyboard"               ".New York"               ".SF Arabic"             
  [5] ".SF Compact"             "System Font"             ".SF NS Mono"             ".SF NS Rounded"         
  [9] "Academy Engraved LET"    "Andale Mono"             "Apple Braille"           "AppleMyungjo"           
 [13] "Arial Black"             "Arial"                   "Arial Narrow"            "Arial Rounded MT Bold"  
 [17] "Arial Unicode MS"        "Bodoni Ornaments"        "Bodoni 72 Smallcaps"     ""
```

Then run this code:

```
theme_Publication <- function(base_size = 15, base_family = 'sans') {
  (theme_foundation(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family)
   + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2), face = 'bold', hjust = 0.5),
           text = element_text(),
           panel.background = element_rect(colour = NA),
           plot.background = element_rect(colour = NA),
           panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA),
           axis.title = element_text(face = 'bold', size = rel(1)),
           axis.title.y = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5, size = 10),
           axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.5, size = 10),
           axis.text = element_text(size = rel(0.8)),
           axis.line = element_line(colour='black', size = 1.2),
           axis.ticks = element_line(),
           panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
           panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
           legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA),
           legend.position = 'right',
           legend.key.size= unit(0.2, 'cm'),
           legend.margin = margin(t = 0, unit='cm'),
           legend.title = element_text(face='italic'),
           plot.margin=unit(c(2.5,5,2.5,5),'mm'),
           strip.background=element_rect(colour='#F0F0F0',fill='#F0F0F0'),
           strip.text = element_text(face='bold')
   )
  )
}

df <- data.frame(x = c(71.33,   74.98 ,  80 , 85.35  , 90.03),
                 y = c(119.17,  107.73 , 99.72 ,  75,  54.59))

(b = ggplot(df)+
    geom_col(aes(x, y), position = "dodge") +
    xlab('x') +
    ylab('y') +
    labs(title = 'Example') +
    theme_Publication() +
    theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial")))

# Set working directory
setwd("/Users/name/Downloads/")
pdf("Your_plot.pdf")
# plot
b
dev.off()
```

Your output plot with Arial text:

[image]

Comment: the problem is that if I add the line specifying the Arial font (theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial")))), neither your code nor other ways of making a pdf 
 work, and I get this error: Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid font type

Comment: @ChiaraToschi I added code to install fonts like Arial. After doing that you are able to create the plot with arial text like above.

Comment: thank you, however for some reason it doesn't load any fonts. it gives me this error: No FontName. Skipping.
/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/PartyLET-plain.ttfsh: line 1: 40973 Segmentation fault: 11  '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rttf2pt1/exec//ttf2pt1' -a -GfAe '/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/PartyLET-plain.ttf' '/var/folders/sv/x43js19x55b7mjtz7sfc9fvm0000gn/T//Rtmplg7Wv5/fonts/PartyLET-plain' 2>&1 .  and if I try to load fonts it says NULL: > loadfonts(quiet = T)
> fonts()
NULL
>