# Change font family to math italic in ggplot element_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an R code chunk in an LyX file that creates a graph. I would like to label the axes of this graph in a math italic font. It seems to me that the thing to do is to add a theme with an entry along the lines of:

```
axis.title = element_text(family = "XXX", face = "italic", size = 14))
```

But regardless of what I try, I keep getting the following error message

```
In grid.call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
      font family not found in Windows font database
```

How can I select the same font that LyX uses for mathematics, and independently of the operating system?

Comment: Do you have `XXX` font installed in your system?

Comment: When I look for fonts I get `> windowsFonts()
$serif
[1] "TT Times New Roman"

$sans
[1] "TT Arial"

$mono
[1] "TT Courier New"`
But this can't be right - LyX has a wide range of fonts that it uses, and I don't my code to run only on Windows

Comment: So I think you need to install that font at first.

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71362738/r-error-in-grid-callc-textbounds-as-graphicsannotxlabel-xx-xy-polygo) helps?